# Is there any fast way I can use to import React.js Material Icons in just Single line?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, icons

I was working on my first react.js project as beginner & I got annoyed by the fact that I have import material UI icons one-by-one & that made my code look really really long & I had to keep on visiting browser, COPY the Icon link again & again. So I was wondering if there's a way I can use to just group together all the Icons that I need from Material UI & just import one line of code containing all the Icons I need?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

`import { AccessAlarm, ThreeDRotation } from '@material-ui/icons';`

So you just make a list of the ones you want. This is from the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/) option #2.

Comment: Hey @tmdesigned thank you... I look at it now